# how to put stackpanel style property in style and setter

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

how can put the below style property into style , setter

```
                <StackPanel >
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF707070"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                </StackPanel>
```

it thing it may like

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="Psp">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" ></Setter>       
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value >
            <StackPanel >
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF707070"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

it giving error  on  `<Setter.Value >`

> Specified value cannot be assigned, the following type is expected
>   "Brush"

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource Psp}">
                <TextBlock Text="This is a test"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every i have solve this problem

```
   <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="Psp">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,3,5" />
        <Setter  Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brushh}" ></Setter>   
    </Style>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brushh" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF707070"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="Psp">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" ></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value >
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF707070"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In your page

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource Psp}">
            <TextBlock Text="This is a test"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

You can obviously define the style on the page level or control level too.

Comment: what error is it giving you? is this error in the xaml at design time or when you compile?

Comment: Just seen your edit, your style as you currently have it is invalid, you can't set the background of a control as a stackpanel, hence  <Setter.Value ><StackPanel > is wrong, it has to be a brush, as defined in this answer.

Comment: Thanks Funksf, i have done please see the below answer